# Use Checkboxes with Drupal Better Exposed filter

Tags: views

[Better Exposed Filters](https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) is not showing the option for Radio buttons and Check boxes. How do I enable it?

Better Exposed Filter working well and good until I enable the Auto Submit option. My Check boxes are gone and shows simply the list. So I uncheck the auto submit, but still i don't get the options to choose.

The filter criteria are set to "Content: Has taxonomy term"; the selection type is "Dropdown."

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

This also tripped me up. The settings weren't where I expected them to be and there were a couple of prerequisites. Maybe this is your issue too?

1. Create a View and expose a filter
2. Under *Advanced > Exposed form > Exposed form style* select *Better Exposed Filters*
3. Under *BEF Settings* roll down to the bottom where there are the *Exposed Filter settings* and select Checkboxes/Radio Buttons from the drop down menu.

**Note**: You can't select these settings for filters that don't have a limited number of options. (A title won't work, but a term will.) [The documentation](https://drupal.org/node/766974) says:

> BEF only operates on fields that have a limited number of options such as Node:Type or Taxonomy:TermID. Open-ended fields, such as Node:Title, do not work with BEF. Entity References do work, however, if you Enable Render Views filters as select list (a checkbox) in the Entity's entityreference field.

I had utilized the entity reference field pattern. You need to edit the field you are referencing in the *Content types > [content type] > manage fields > [field name] > edit*. field settings. There, at the bottom of the page under *Additional Behaviours* you will find a checkbox for *Render Views filters*. That will allow the aforementioned select box (in BEF settings) to properly display the Checkbox/Radio option.

Comment: Better Exposed Filter working well and good until i enable the Auto Submit option. My Check boxes are gone and shows simply the list. So i uncheck the auto submit, but still i don't get the options to choose.

Filter criteria:
Content: Has taxonomy term

Selection type
Dropdown

http://i939.photobucket.com/albums/ad238/dhineshr/Screenshotfrom2013-08-...
http://i939.photobucket.com/albums/ad238/dhineshr/Screenshotfrom2013-08-...
http://i939.photobucket.com/albums/ad238/dhineshr/Screenshotfrom2013-08-...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to make checkboxes list for nodes. Here is a good manual for Drupal 6: [Filtering A View By A List Of Nodes With Checkboxes](http://www.civicactions.com/blog/2011/apr/15/filtering_a_view_by_a_list_of_nodes_with_checkboxes). It helped me with D7 also.

For Drupal 7 it requires several code modifications. Unfortunately, there is no possibility to add comments on this blog with code changes for D7.