# Checkbox for Views Filter

Tags: 7, views

I have a view and used [Better Exposed Filter module](https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) to show this Checkbox to filter the content in the view. The picture may explain the situation properly
[image: View Filter with exposed Checkbox]

In above filter by criteria, those values are Taxonomy Terms, which will increase later.

However my problem is, I want to have a Checkbox only for **Development** Taxonomy. So, instead of **Filter by** and list of Taxonomies, it would only be **Filter by Development** with a checkbox near to it. When the checkbox is checked it'd show the view which is **Listed Under** only **Development**

I tried something like CSS or jQuery show only this taxonomy class and hide other taxonomy terms, but that's last resort.

Any Drupal way I can accomplish this without writing codes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drupal Better Exposed filter](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82847/drupal-better-exposed-filter)

Comment: @squarecandy No it doesn't seem to be a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your filter settings there is an option "Limit to the selected items".
Check that and select "Development" from the select field of options and it should do what you are trying to achieve.

Then change the label of your filter as required.

See the attached image:
[image]

The view itself looks like (note I changed the filter to be cat, not car as in the previous image, because I already had content tagged with cat):
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I could accomplish this easily with new `Field` as `Text or list`, but it is quite challenging to do with `Taxonomy`. I might be referring to something else using `Taxonomy` as when I check the box, no any result shows. But same filter with new `text field` works perfectly.

Comment: I had to give up the idea of using `Taxonomy` here, as taxonomy is mere term reference which doesn't technically lie in my content type.

Comment: The example screenshot I included was from me doing it with a taxonomy field.

Comment: But are you using `BEF Module` with this? If so, then It'd be great to see your filtered screenshot

Comment: Yep, I already had BEF installed on my play site for something else. Image attached in the answer.

Comment: I got it working. The problem was in `Taxonomy` filter criteria there was extra settings which had `select list` and `autocomplete`. While selecting `autocomplete` it showed to me `some illegal things, contact site admin` something like that. But when I changed it to `select list` its working. I can't understand the issue, but glad its working anyhow. Thanks !!!